# Once for all, someone might explain the role of each proxy_buffer* directives for nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

As a result of this error:

> upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

I have come across the following recommendation or config file:

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

However, from what I can understand by reading [the nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffer_size), `proxy_buffers` directive also sets the size of the buffer, that is, the actual *effective* buffer size will be **256k** and not **128k**, so I wonder, how about the following:

```
proxy_buffer_size   256k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Is it okay?

Can I set it to even larger?

What is means to have 512k or 1024k, will it improve speed and performance, or slow down server's responsiveness?

And what is the role of that `proxy_busy_buffers_size` shall it be as twice as buffer_size, half of it, similar to?

It is really confusing, and I am convinced, a canonical guide will be useful the rest of us.